# TypeScript AMD module inheritance not working

Tags: typescript, inheritance, requirejs

I've got a bunch of TypeScript files which use `extends` inheritance. Example:

```
export class AdminModule extends ModuleBase {
    constructor(moduleData: IModuleData) {
         super(moduleData);
    }
}
```

They are built with the following `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "amd",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "Typings/**/*"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "App/**/*"
  ]
}
```

The compiler includes this script to all files which inherit something.

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
    extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
        ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
        function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
    return extendStatics(d, b);
}
return function (d, b) {
    extendStatics(d, b);
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
})();
```

Now I'm trying to load everything with requirejs, but I get the following error at the line `extendStatics(d, b);`.

> TypeError: Object.setPrototypeOf: expected an object or null, got undefined

Looking at the stack trace, it seems that the base class has not been loaded and is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it - it simply was a circular reference causing that error.
See: https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular